# How do you have a background image (of container) fit the screen width-wide, but not get cut off height-wise?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

Now I now that question sounded confusing so I'm going to try to explain it simply. I have an image I'd like to use in a jumbotron element on a html page. I'd like the image to take up ~95% of the page width wise while never cutting off the image. I'd also like to maintain the aspect ratio for the purpose of maximum image quality. The image is 3225x2656.

Thanks for your help! Appreciate it.

Comment: can you put margins of 2.5% on both the left and the right?

Comment: I could but the image is going to be cut off on the bottom still. Could I somehow set the container size to expand to the height of the image?

Comment: I'm thinking `height=100%` and `width="auto"`. Can you whip up a quick fiddle to test it out?

Comment: Through it up on voiddevelopment.com (a misc domain I have).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QyP7yL2X

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zuB0d6DG

Comment: @AllenF. have you seen my answer yet?

Comment: Basically, I am looking for a way to change the size of the jumbotron container to maintain the aspect ratio of the background image.

Comment: Your dimensions are not standard.  A typical widescreen ratio is 16:9,  an old TV ratio is 4:3, so percentage wise widescreen height is 56.25%, TV ratio is 75% height. Your image turns out to be 82% that's abnormally tall. an ipad in portrait mode or the higher end smartphones and iphones shouldn't have a problem, but you might have to crop that image for the rest of your viewers.

Comment: So I should simply drop the image so that its width:height ratio is 16:9?

Comment: @zer00ne I cropped the image however its still getting cut off. What corresponding CSS Code should I add to it so that it doesn't mess up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
max-height: 82%
margin: 0 auto;
```